# Identity Server 3 AzureAd Claims not returning

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver3, openid-connect

I have a working Identity Server application, and I'm setting it up to work with Azure AD. I've got my Azure Ad App registration and I can authenticate with it properly.

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743078/identity-server-4-register-users-from-external-providers) and trying to do something similar to store the 3rd party user IDs associated with a user, but I'm not getting the `sub` or `nameIdentifier` claims back from AAD.

Do I need to request these from AzureAD somehow? - Their docs seem to be to be saying that the "sub" claim is (or at least can be) returned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#_subject. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/claims) article seems to say that sub isn't returned, but it's for multitenant applications, so I'm not too sure if that's relevant.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but can't find anything relevant on Google.

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

The article [Work with claims-based identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/claims) is too old and this [Azure AD token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#_subject) article should be right about the token claims in the token issued by Azure AD.

Based on the test, I could get the `sub` claim from Azure AD and it also issued by the IdentityServer3 like figure below:
[image]

Here is the code I configed for the IdentityServer3 for your reference:

```
var webApp = WebApp.Start("https://localhost:44333", app =>
{
    app.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
    {
        SiteName = "NDC Demo",
        SigningCertificate = cert,
        Factory = factory,
        AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
        {
            IdentityProviders = ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders,
            EnableAutoCallbackForFederatedSignout = true
        }
    });
});

public static void ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
{
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "aad",
        Caption = "Azure AD",
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,

        Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}",
        ClientId = "{clientIdFromAzurePortal}",
        RedirectUri = "{redirectUri}",
    });
}
```

If you still have the problem, would you mind sharing the request to Azure AD which you can capture it using Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks @fie-xue-msft. My Fiddler trace is the same as yours. How do you get the raw response token from AAD? Perhaps I need to include some specific scopes to get it back? Do you get the subject claim returned as part of IDS' `AuthenticateExternalAsync` method? This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510679/getting-users-token-subject-identifier-sub-from-within-azure-ad) says that I should look at `oid` rather than `sub`, but the question is a year old.

Comment: As the code in the post, the IdentityServer3 interact Azure AD with Open ID connection protocol. And to narrow down whether this issue was caused by Azure AD or Identity Server3, I suggest that you decode the id_token return from Azure AD from this [site](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: And as far as I know, the only `sub` is the stand claim which supported by Open ID connection(refer [here](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims)).